# On Android, How to create global screen overlay for my app?

Tags: android, overlay

I want to display some icon as alert for my app.

I know there are screen dimmer/filter apps that can do the thing on Android, but I cannot find technical reference on the topic from google.

Anyone can point me the way?

Comment: Hello @somebody4 do you want to icon as in alert(Dialog) in app or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- using `context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)` to get a
  `WindowManager`
- create layoutParams: `WindowManager.LayoutParams(-2, -2, TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, 0, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)`
- create view using `context`
- then use `WindowManager.addView`
- may need to add permission `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`